# Rails 2 ":defaults" js conflict w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

When I use a `javascript_include_tag` for both jQuery and Rails' `:defaults`, the latter one seems to override the first.

For instance, when I put elements in this order:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

...I can execute an AJAX update with Rails but can do nothing with jQuery.
When I reverse the order of the `javascript_include_tag`s, I can access jQuery but cannot run an AJAX request with Rails.

I prefer to do my AJAX Rails (as it entails less code on my part), but I wish also to make use of other jQuery features.  Any idea what to do or where the conflict lies?

Rails 2.3.5,
jQuery 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two easy solutions here. Use the [jrails](https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) plugin. It will walk you through what you need to do.

Or use jQuery instead of $ in your jQuery code.

For example:

```
$('li').fadeOut();
// should be
jQuery('li').fadeOut();
```

They will do the same thing but Rails uses Prototype which also maps the $ and therefore conflicts with jQuery.

Comment: jquery-rails is really for rails 3.0. And probably won't work the same (if at all) in rails 2.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and use $j instead of $ for jQuery.

`<script> 
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add defaults first and then jquery. The conflict is between prototype.js file and jquery-1.4.2.min file

```
<%= javascript_include_tag  :defaults %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.2.min' %>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

use $j instead of $ like.

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
.............
});
```